# Excel ADDRESS and COUNTIF function

Tags: excel, function, cell, countif, excel-indirect

I use the following function to count the number of days present:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:T2,"=P")
```

It works great in cell U2.

Now I want to use Address function instead, to select the previous cell instead of T2:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDIRECT(ROW(CELL("address")))-1,
     INDIRECT(COLUMN(CELL("address")))-1)),"=p")
```

It is not working ;(

Please, help.

Comment: Try `INDIRECT("C2:"&ADDRESS(INDIRECT(ROW(CELL("address")))-1&INDIRECT(COLUMN(CELL("address")))-1))` instead of `C2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDIRECT(ROW(CELL("address")))-1,INDIRECT(COLUMN(CELL("address")))-1))`.

Comment: What do you mean with "the previous cell" in this example? S2? T1? Please explain in words what you want to calculate, i.e. the logic, then we can help you find a formula for it. This can possibly be done with Index instead of Indirect and Address.

Comment: U2 is the cell where the formula is written
T2 is the previous cell

Answer (score 1):

Indirect and Address can probably be replaced with a simple Index.

How about

```
=COUNTIF(C2:Index(2:2,column()-2,"=P")
```

In words: perform a countif on the range from C2 to the cell in row 2 that is 2 columns to the left of the current column.

If that does not answer your question, please edit it and explain the logic in similar words.